# Javascript webpage doesn't work on localhost, but OK as file:///

Tags: javascript, localhost, ubuntu-14.04

but... `file:///home/me/public_html/path/index.html` everything works fine...

I'm trying to get a javascript page to run locally. (Using Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache)

When I open the file `file:///home/me/public_html/path/to/index.html` directory from file manager the webpage javascript runs fine all OK. (by double clicking the index.html file)

When I open it in chrome/firefox using `localhost/~me/path/to/index.html` only the html is rendered - the javascript doesn't run.

What have I missed or have failed to account for?

The js source files look like this:

```
<script src="libraries/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/tinycolor.js"></script>
```

---

[Solved] it was the subdirectory permissions... they were `drwx------`and should have been `drwxr-xr-x` - localhost works now.

Comment: The most obvious reason would be that you have absolute paths to your javascript files. Can you post the content of the html file?

Comment: I added the .js source links  - it is downloaded from here http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/jquery-colorpickersliders/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `FireBug` in Firefox and view the `Console` tab. If you found any `Network Error`, then there is a problem for your `Apache` to perform requests.

When I faced the same problem, it was the issue of my WAMP stack not able to perform requests due to installation of `Bitnami Stacks` which were interfering with the `Apache` of WAMP.

Comment: Ah-ha - I get 403 forbidden - on all the sources stuff in subdirectories. OK it looks like the permissions may not be set correctly - they are drwx------. In other pages' subdirectories that do work they are drwxrwxr-x. So that might be it.

Comment: Yes! Most probably the user permissions.

Comment: Confirmed that was the problem and fixed! I changed the directory permissions to drwxr-xr-x and it works on localhost. Thanks!!